# Opencv has found image that doesn't exist on screen

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I try to use opencv for search button location on screen. If button exist on screen opencv work perfect but it return some !=0 x,y even if image doesn't exist. How to fix it?

```
import cv2
def buttonlocation(image):
    im = ImageGrab.grab()
    im.save('screenshot.png')
    img = cv2.imread(image,0)
    img2 = img.copy()
    template = cv2.imread('screenshot.png',0)
    w,h = template.shape[::-1]
    meth = 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF'
    img = img2.copy()
    method = eval(meth)
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    top_left = min_loc
    x,y = top_left
    return x,y
```

Comment: A [mcve] would be nice...

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of opencv](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) details to two steps of the template matching procedure.

1. `R=cv2.matchTemplate(I,T,method)` computes an image `R`. Each pixel `x,y` of this image represents a mark depending on the similarity between the template `T` and the sub-image of `I` starting at `x,y`. For instance, if the method `cv.TM_SQDIFF` is applied, the mark is computed as:

[image]

If `R[x,y]` is null, then the sub-image `I[x:x+sxT,y:y+syT]` is exactly identical to the template `T`. The smaller `R[x,y]` is, the closer to the template the sub-image is.

2. `cv2.minMaxLoc(R)` is applied to find the minimum of `R`. The corresponding subimage of `I` is expected to closer to the template than any other sub-image of `I`.

If the image `I` does not contain the template, the sub-image of `I` corresponding to the minimum of `R` can be very different from `T`. But the value of the minimum reflects this ! **Indeed, a threshold on `R` can be applied as a way to decide whether the template is in the image or not.**

Choosing the value for the threshold is a tricky task. It could be a fraction of the maximum value of `R` or a fraction of the mean value of R. The influence of the size of the template can be discarted by dividing `R` by the `sxT*syT`. For instance, the maximum value of `R` depends on the template size and the type of the image. For instance, for CV_8UC3 (unsigned char, 3 channels) the maximum value of `R` is `255*3*sxT*syT`.

Here is an example:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',eval('cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR'))
template = cv2.imread('template.jpg',eval('cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR'))

cv2.imshow('image',img)
#cv2.waitKey(0)
#cv2.destroyAllWindows()

meth = 'cv2.TM_SQDIFF'
method = eval(meth)
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = min_loc
x,y = top_left
h,w,c=template.shape

print 'R='+str( min_val)
if min_val< h*w*3*(20*20):
    cv2.rectangle(img,min_loc,(min_loc[0] + w,min_loc[1] + h),(0,255,0),3)
else:
    print 'first template not found'

template = cv2.imread('template2.jpg',eval('cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR'))
res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,method)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
top_left = min_loc
x,y = top_left
h,w,c=template.shape

print 'R='+str( min_val)
if min_val< h*w*3*(20*20):
    cv2.rectangle(img,min_loc,(min_loc[0] + w,min_loc[1] + h),(0,0,255),3)
else:
    print 'second template not found'

cv2.imwrite( "result.jpg", img);

cv2.namedWindow('res',0)
cv2.imshow('res',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The image:
[image]

The first template is to be found:
[image]

The second template is not to be found:
[image]

The result:
[image]